# Why am I now unable to write a file after importing pymem.process?

Tags: python

This may have a simple explanation but I'm tired and frustrated. I really just need to be able to use pymem and write a file at the same time. Here's what I'm running into:

```
f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write("")
```

This works fine and the file is created as expected.

However:

```
from pymem.process import *

f = open("file.txt", "w")
f.write("")
```

Gives me the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\GitHub\mificat\create_file_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    f.write("")
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'write'
```

I looked at the methods imported with pymem.process and I think a method I'm importing is probably interfering with open() but I'm not sure, and not sure how to work around it. I was expecting to simply be able to output a file as usual while using pymem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pymem.process` [has its own `open` method](https://pymem.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#pymem.process.open). This is one reason that

```py
from foo import *
```

is an antipattern: `pymem.process.open` is included with `from pymem.process import *`, and it shadows the built-in `open` function. Essentially, `open` becomes `pymem.process.open`.

Instead, import just what you need:

```py
from pymem.process import foo, bar
```

Or, import the module and qualify your calls:

```py
import pymem.process

pymem.process.foo()
```

If you want to use `pymem.process.open` and don't want to have to qualify it, you can import it with a different name:

```py
from pymem.process import open as pymem_open

pymem_open(...)
```

(Note that the upstream library can specify what should be included in `*`, choosing to omit `open` if they wish. But it looks like they aren't doing that.)

Answer (score 0):

`pymem.process` has its own `open` method. You should never import something like

`from pymem.process import *`

This is considered a bad practice. Always state explicitly what methods you want to import, like this:

`from pymem.process import list_processes`

or you can do this:

`from pymem import process`

and then use it like this:

`process.list_processes()`

in case you want to use `list_processes()` method from `pymem.process`